# How to orthogonally upper-triangularize a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices, triangularization

Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
     -2 & 7 \\ 5 &3 
     \end{bmatrix}$$

Using the triangularization theorem, I want to find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{T}A P$ is an upper triangular matrix.

---

I have the answer

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{6}{37} \sqrt{38}&\frac{1}{37} \sqrt{52} \\ \frac{-1}{37} \sqrt{37}
 & \frac{6}{37} \sqrt{37}\end{bmatrix}$$

but I am very confused on how to get this matrix $P$. Does anyone know the process? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We have $AP=PT$

In particular, we have $$AP_1 = T_{11}P_1$$
$$AP_2 = T_{12}P_1 + T_{22}P_2 = P\begin{bmatrix} T_{12} \\ T_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$

After picking $P_1$ to be an eigenvector with unit length, just pick $P_2$ to be orthogonal to $P_1$.

We then compute $$\begin{bmatrix} T_{12} \\ T_{22}\end{bmatrix} = P^TAP_2$$

Extra exercises: Think of how many possible $P$'s you can pick for this question.

Comment: what is p1? and p2 ? exactly?

Comment: @Logan The columns of $P$, I assume.

Comment: The two columns of $P$.

Comment: I don't understand, you said p1 is an eigenvector, so in this case is (1,2)^T that is an eigenvector of A, how do you pick a p2 that is orthogonal to p1?

Comment: If we have $P_1 = (u_1, u_2)^T$, then we can just pick $P_2=(-u_2, u_1)^T$.

Comment: but how do you know T11 and T22 ?